# Howto obtain caller id from analog phone within Java (Asterisk PBX ?)

Tags: java, asterisk

### Looking for

Hi guys, I would like to obtain the caller id from an analog phone with the help of Asterisk. Afterwards the caller id will be processed within my java app (comparing the caller id with phone number stored in a database).

### My Inquiry

I have researched that following components are needed:

1. a linux machine with an installed ***Asterisk PBX Server*** connected to a network
2. the same linux machine to run my java app which needs to include an ***Asterisk-Java package***
   (https://github.com/asterisk-java/asterisk-java)
3. a ***VOIP Analog-Telephone-Adapter*** such as Grandstream HandyTone HT701 to integrate the analog phone into the network

### Need your advice and suggestion

- Since I am completely new to this topic I am really dependent on your
  invaluable input about whether my **inquired setup is the right
  direction to go** or are there better solutions to cope with this
  project's requirement?
- Moreover if you **agree completely** with my inquiry, could you tell
  me how to setup a connection between the Asterisk PBX Server and
  the    VOIP Analog-Telephone-Adapter? Are **drivers needed**?

Comment: Have a look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36063942/calling-a-php-script-using-freepbx-and-asterisk/36068123#36068123 it might give you an idea.

Comment: Hi there, thanks for your reply. I just need someone to look at my approach and tell me if it is the right way to do. Your suggested link already goes too deep into the matter and centers around php, which I don't need.

Comment: You are right about approach exactly. Probably most difficult part will be to configure Asterisk, what involve set-up of SIP account for your Grandstream ATA. ATA is easy to configure, there is manuals online. No drivers is needed, it works via SIP protocol and connects via Ethernet cable, only you should make sure that Asterisk box and ATA are on same network.What you mean by "Or use Asterisk Server to lookup the IP address of the VOIP ATA?"?

Comment: My example is php specific but the AGI (What you need to get the CLI out of asterisk) is the bit I was thinking you should have a look at.

Comment: @os11k Thanks for your answer. So you agree with my chain of thoughts :D. With **"Or use Asterisk Server to lookup the IP address of the VOIP ATA?"** I was asking how to make the Asterisk Server find and connect to the ATA. Do I just input the IP address of the ATA into the Asterisk Server configuration file?

Comment: @user3788685 You are absolutely right. Do you have some experience with the package Asterisk Java? It uses FastAGI for Java to connect to the Asterisk Server.

Comment: sadly I'm not a Java person at all. But I found some slightly dated info on FastAGI at http://www.voip-info.org/wiki/view/Asterisk+FastAGI

Comment: Please check Asterisk manuals for setting out ATA and Asterisk, but one way to configure Asterisk is to providing IP(and other information) of ATA or you can set-up password based authentication(in both cases ATA needs to know Asterisk IP, but in second Asterisk don't care what ip ATA have).

Comment: @os11k Thanks a lot for your information! I really appreciate it! You have helped me to understand Asterisk a whole chunk better!

Comment: @os11k Do you know if it is possible to configure the ATA automatically to connect to Asterisk Server but if none is found (Server is down) the ATA will  use the SIP account that is stored with the ATA config. I just want the ATA still being able to send/receive calls when the Server is down.

Comment: No, you need always server running if you are using regular ATA. You can run Asterisk on Rapsberi Pi in case if you don't want to have regular size PC near your ATA, or you can even run server in digitalocean or AWS, but in this case when there is no internet connectivity between ATA and server, calls will not go through.